# After conversion, Paramount OS is super squirrely

Tags: conversion, handling

All,

I have a custom made Paramount OS from 1991. I converted the bike to be my bike for family rides. To do this, I replaced the handlebars and put larger tires on the rim ~ nothing crazy, just a broader, more durable road tire.

The bike is beyond squirrely. Prior to the conversion, it was easy to ride no handed (Paramount's didn't have the shortest wheelbase's or the most aggressive geometry), now it's actually difficult to ride with one hand on the bars, let alone none.

EDIT-

BY squirly, I mean the bike's handling is loosey-goosey,touchy,unstable etc. I swapped from Cinelli drops to a straigh-bar, don't know the length. No trouble with the fork, headset and no other changes. Perhaps the weight dist. is off as someone suggested.
I turned this bike into a kicker as I wanted to upgrade to shifters on the drops, but the rear triangles on my OS were too narrow to accommodate the 8 gear cassette.
FH

What might be causing this?

Comment: can you define "squirly"?

Comment: Unbalanced tire

Comment: What "conversion" did you do - cut down the handlebars to 20cm wide? Swapped from 622 wheels to 406?

Comment: What handle bar conversion did you do?  Drop to straight?  Drop to swept back?  This can have a large effect on the weight distribution over the front wheel.

Comment: I had a squirrely bike - turned out to be subtly bent forks which made braking and potholes and bumps a bit of a white-knuckle moment.   What does yours do that rates this description?

Comment: Could be a worn headset - that can make a bike almost impossible to ride with no hands.

Comment: A worn headset or an overly tight headset. If the headset has loose bearings there could be one too many or one too few. Had the problem with a motorbike once where the workshop put one too many ball bearings in the headset and the thing wouldn't go in a straight line anymore.

Comment: How much taller is the tire than the previous one? Adding 25mm of height to the front end will slacken the head tube angle by 1 degree. Which is enough to change handling.

Comment: What's a "kicker" ?  What is OS and FH?

Comment: Criggie, A kicker is a bike one uses to knock-around on. OS refers to the oversizing tubing Schwinn used when their Waterford, WI made Paramount frames. FH are my initials.

Comment: So your saddle is in the same place?

Answer (score 1):

If the headset is good then you need look at tire balance

The tire itself could be out of balance and also it could not be seated evenly.

Examine how tires are seated.

Put it on a stand or upside down and see if the wheels hold in position. Rotate 1/8 turn and check all 8 positions.

For the rear you can spin the pedals - at high speed does it wobble?

If not balance then pull the tire and remount it.